# What is the difference between "e.currentTarget.href" and ".getAttribute('href')"?

Tags: javascript, html, attributes, href

```js
var a = document.querySelector("a");
console.log( a.href == a.getAttribute("href") ); //why false? (tested on chrome)
```

```html
<a href="#hello">Link</a>
```

Why is the output false? I mean, I know `.href` is returning the whole URL, while `.getAttribute()` only returns the part that is actually written on the HTML, that is why result of the comparison is false. **But I wonder if this is how it is suppose to be according to spec and why**. Also, I wonder if this happens with any other attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason the property is always a full URL is in the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-48250443):

> `href` **of type** `DOMString`
>   The absolute URI [IETF RFC 2396] of the linked resource.

---

The difference comes from one being an attribute (`<a href="#hello">`) and the other being a property (`a.href`). An attribute is equal to whatever value is set in the markup. The property is only initialized by the attribute, but can have any other ("matching") value. Setting the property overrides the attribute though, and setting the attribute again results in discrepancies:

```js
var a = document.querySelector('a');
a.href = a.href;
alert('Setting the property: ' + a.href + ' ' + a.getAttribute('href'));
a.setAttribute('href', '#goodbye');
alert('Setting the attribute: ' + a.href + ' ' + a.getAttribute('href'));
```

```html
<a href="#hello">Link</a>
```

Regarding other attributes, for example, the href attribute / property of the `<link>` element behaves in the same manner:

```js
alert(document.getElementById('lnk').href);
```

```html
<link id="lnk" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="some.css"></link>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `href` property gives you the absolute path while the `getAttribute` method returns the exact value of the attribute.

```js
var a = document.querySelector("a");
alert( a.href + " " + a.getAttribute("href") ); // http://stacksnippets.net/js#hello #hello
```

```html
<a href="#hello">Link</a>
```

Comment: I know that, but why is it that way?

Comment: @Vandervals That's how it is supposed to be. It's like asking why `NaN === NaN` is false. :) The `getAttribute` method is obvious, I guess. The `href` field is the computed value, how the browser understands it.

Answer (score 0):

getAttribute() Method always return the value of that attribute. If you want get any value of any attribute that time you can use getAttribute method.

while the HREF preperty always returns the URL of the linked Document.So both result may be sometime same when you use absolute path otherwise both returns different.