# puppeteer; cannot get valid href from $$eval()

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, puppeteer

artmiami.com uses  on many pages.
pg.$$eval('a', (El) => El.map((el) => el.href))
returns results links like "artmiami.com/hotels/admin" or  "artmiami.com/logos/admin"
when it should return "/admin" or "artmiami.com/admin"
I could work around if it were possible to get the el.html() in $$eval()

Comment: correction
should read:
artmiami.com uses "a href=/admin" on many pages

Comment: You can [edit] corrections into your post.

Answer (score 2):

you need to use [`.getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute), which returns the value of an attribute, instead of [`.href`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAnchorElement/href), which returns a whole URL:

```
await page.$$eval('a', (El) => El.map((el) => el.getAttribute('href')))
```

see here:

[Why is different e.currentTarget.href and .getAttribute("href")?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33208771/why-is-different-e-currenttarget-href-and-getattributehref)

Comment: thanks it helped. 
anyway puppeteer should not return an INVALID url in case one uses .href

Comment: @GeraldTrost it's returning an absolute URL when using .href, not sure what you mean by invalid, and there seems to be no cases you mention, such as "/hotels/admin"..

Comment: As I pointed out:
it SHOULD return an absolute URL
BUT IT DOES NOT - it returns a non-existing invalid URL
this is the bug I tried to describe

Comment: to make it clear to you
an anchor href=/xx on the page aa.com/bb MUST NOT RETURN
aa.com/bb/xx BUT IT MUST RETURN aa.com/xx
this is because the href is absolute, it starts with a slash

Comment: @GeraldTrost like said, I didn't notice such cases anywhere. I don't know what goes on on pages behind login also.. try running the code in your browser's console

Comment: nooo - nothing goes on behind the scenes
it is simply a bug as shown in my articel -
it returns an invalid  non-existing url
I am quite sure that the browser console would return the correct url
but I dont know hor to run puppeteer in the browser

Comment: @GeraldTrost run puppeteer in full mode: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer#default-runtime-settings and then open console and debug